# Remove DOM node without leaving whitespace

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this HTML:

```
... foo<span id="baz"/>bar ...
```

and I want:

```
... foobar ...
```

If I just do:

```
var elem = document.getElementByID('baz');
elem.parentNode.remove(elem);
```

I'm left with:

```
... foo bar ...
```

I can't just remove all spaces since that would kill the rest of my page, and I can't add any more HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `getElementById` (*not uppercase ID*), and `removeChild` instead of `remove`

```
var elem = document.getElementById('baz');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

And if your html is indeed as you point then it is invalid as `span` is not a self-closing tag (*in HTML documents*).. it should be `<span></span>`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/uC5tA/1/